# pBlazSim Picoblaze simulator - Trouble Getting Started

Tags: xilinx, picoblaze

I've been trying to simulate my Picoblaze code with pBlazSim, but I'm having trouble with the lack of documentation. Am I missing something? Could someone point me in the right direction?

Edit - I've been confused as to how to add software emulation of external components - there's references to pBlazIDE, the previous software, in ug129 from Xilinx, but I'm finding a complete dearth of information on the newer software. Using pBlazIDE, single stepping the code we have works just fine, but doing multiple runs having to switch inputs on and off by clicking a box is really frustrating after a few hours - we'd like to automate that portion, using the 'newer' pBlazSIM, but are having trouble finding a community of practice.

I apologize the question wasn't more fully worded - Christmas is distracting.

Comment: not constructive and doesn't show any effort.

Comment: What have you tried? What are the issues? have you been able to even start using it?

Comment: I've been confused as to how to add software emulation of external components - there's references to pBlazIDE, the previous software, in ug129 from Xilinx, but I'm finding a complete dearth of information on the newer software.

Using pBlazIDE, single stepping the code we have works just fine, but doing multiple runs having to switch inputs on and off is really frustrating after a few hours - we'd like to automate that portion, using the 'newer' pBlazSIM, but are having trouble finding a community of practice. 

I apologize the question wasn't more fully worded - Christmas is distracting.

Answer (score 1):

The IDE is just a very simple bit of software to write the code in, and do some very basic testing - I an not aware of any automation features for pBlazeIDE which is what have been using, but according to trayres you can write scripts for pBlazSIM to control the I/O (not pBlazeIDE which is a different tool), so I'd check this out. For the complete picture you really have to simulate it in ISim (or ModelSim or whatever you are using) and use your testbench to drive the inputs.

I just point the output of the Picoblaze IDE to generate the files in the Xilinx project folder (so it overwrites the old version automatically), then you can make a change, compile and simulate quickly.

Comment: From the Mediatronix website:
"I/O can be scripted by QtScript, a javascript implementation for Qt."

Comment: @trayres - I just checked and the scripting is actually for *pBlazSIM*, rather than pBlazeIDE which is a different tool - I thought they referred to the same thing.